# Creating indexes in an amazon aws aurora mysql does have a cost?

Tags: mysql, index, aws-aurora

I am looking for informations without finding them.
If I create indexes in a aws aurora mysql instance, do I have to pay?

The only things I found is that you pay for all I/O operations (and for storage), but indexes should optimize I/O operations.

Comment: "*but indexes should optimize I/O operation*" - Sure, but it also *costs* I/O operations to create and maintain indexes too. If your data doesn't change as much as you read from the data, then it *may* be a net gain though. You'd have to talk to AWS as far as how pricing works though.

Comment: Show us some queries and the table definition; we can advise on whether the indexes are optimal for those queries.

Comment: @RickJames we do nomal select with join, nothing so complex. We are talking about table with 50k/100k records max

Comment: Can you at least show us the `WHERE` clause?  A _common_ deficiency is to have multiple tests (in `WHERE`), but only single-column `INDEXes`.

Answer (score 3):

Every type of optimization improves one type of query, at the expense of other types of queries.

You can create an index that will reduce I/O operations because it reduces the set of examined rows when you use SELECT, UPDATE, or DELETE, and the conditions in your WHERE clause are optimized by the index.

But keeping that index in sync with the latest changes in the table increases I/O operations.

Furthermore, if your dataset fits in RAM, the I/O operations are also reduced. I/O is incurred when your query requests data that isn't in RAM already. In MySQL, data is loaded into RAM during a query, and there's no reason for it to leave RAM as long as other data doesn't need that same memory. So over time, I/O may be optimized automatically by keeping the most frequently-requested data in RAM.

If you store data that is much larger than RAM, and you can query any random sample of data, on average it will tend to request data that needs to be loaded from storage more frequently. That incurs more I/O.

Amazon is also very vague on what counts as I/O on Aurora. They claim Aurora does some things differently than MySQL, with respect to consolidating I/O to minimize the impact. But they don't provide solid evidence or examples of how this works. Aurora is not MySQL. Amazon has changed a significant amount of internal code, and they do not publish their code as open source.

Ultimately it's difficult to predict or optimize the I/O of an Aurora instance. It depends on the queries you run, the data you query, and the data you queried recently. All you can do is experiment with your own workload, and be prepared to spend a lot of money while you're doing that.